# which process cleans /tmp under systemd on 18.04LTS? (answered here, no duplicate)

Tags: server, system-settings, tmp

There is no /etc/default/rcS anymore on my ubuntu 18.04 server (no GUI) 
I had set TMPTIME=20 and after the upgrade from 16.04 this seems to be reverted to a much shorter time.
How can I customize the cleanup of /tmp ?

There where also other variables in rcS like UTC=yes or FSCKFIX=yes.
Where have those gone?

Comment: with systemd the cleanup of tmp dirs has changed and so this is not a duplicate as the old answers are for older systems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the answer.
I found that with systemd the tmpfiles can be managed from systemctl and the controlling service is systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service.

```
man systemd-tmpfiles
man tmpfiles.d
```

show information about this.

Answer (score 3):

In older ubuntu releases that would be upstart, specifically `/etc/init/mounted-tmp.conf` 
It would still using TMPTIME from `/etc/default/rcS` (but is commented by default). You may need to set those yourself to suit your needs.
But you pointed out ubuntu doesn't use those anymore.

so on case of `systemd` you're looking for:
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf
as described on: 
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/tmpfiles.d.5.html

Comment: That's upstart. 18.04 uses systemd.

Comment: see my updated answer